# projection map is always closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and consider $X\times Y$ with the product topology.

Let $Z$ be a closed subset of $X\times Y$.

Then we can write $Z$ = $X \times Y$ \ $U \times V$ where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$.

But then $Z$ = $X \times Y$ \ $U \times$ $V=((X \setminus U) \times Y) \cup (X \times (Y \setminus V))$.

And now it seems that the projection map $p_Y(Z)=Y$ if $U\neq X$ and $p_Y(Z)=Y\setminus V$ if $U=X$.

But this means that the projection map is always closed which I know is wrong but I fail to see what I'm doing wrong.

Can anybody point out, please. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can't always write a closed subset $Z$ as $Z=X\times Y-U\times V$, for example take $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and $Z = [0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Comment: But by definition of closed sets, isn't $Z$ the complement of some open set, and we know all open sets in the product topology are of the form $U \times V$ where $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: No that is a basis for the topology, all open can't be written as $U\times V$ but as union of such sets.